# Entity subscription with more than one attribute issue

Tags: fiware-orion

I have a entity with some attributes. Each one have a subscription. Here a example of the subscription.

`{
"entities": [
    {
        "type": "Room",
        "isPattern": "false",
        "id": "Room5"
    }
],
"attributes": [ ],
"reference": "http://localhost:5050/notify",
"duration": "P1M",
"notifyConditions": [
    {
        "type": "ONCHANGE",
        "condValues": [
            "pressure"
        ]
    }
]
}`

The problem is that when there's some change in a attribute, the notification subscribe the full entity, including the attributes that have not changed.

Is there any work around to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `attributes` field specifies the attributes to be notified, so if you use an attribute name equal to the one used in `condValues` (instead of an empty list, which means "all the attributes") then the notification will include only the modified attribute. That is:

```
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "Room",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "Room5"
        }
    ],
    "attributes": [ "pressure" ],
    "reference": "http://localhost:5050/notify",
    "duration": "P1M",
    "notifyConditions": [
        {
            "type": "ONCHANGE",
            "condValues": [
                "pressure"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that in this case you need N subscriptions per entity (being N the number of attributes belonging to the entity which values you want to monitor for changes) or per entity type, if your entities can be clasified in types and you use subscriptions with patterns. An example of the latter option is shown below:

```
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "Room",
            "isPattern": "true",
            "id": ".*"
        }
    ],
    "attributes": [ "pressure" ],
    "reference": "http://localhost:5050/notify",
    "duration": "P1M",
    "notifyConditions": [
        {
            "type": "ONCHANGE",
            "condValues": [
                "pressure"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

which causes that everytime the `pressure` of an entity of type `Room` changes (no matter which entity ID) you will get a notification of the pressure for that entity.